# Ignore custom directories in ctrlp.vim

Tags: vim, ctrlp

I want to ignore `dist`, `.git` directories for [ctrlp.vim](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim). And my `.vimrc` configure is below:

```
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = {
  \ 'dir': '\v[\/](\.git|dist)$'
}
```

I have two questions:

- It does not ignore the `dist` directory.
- What is the `\v` mean in the
  statement?

PS: This is my ctrlp configure of `.vimrc`

```
""" ctrlp
   let g:ctrlp_use_caching = 1
   let g:ctrlp_clear_cache_on_exit = 0
   let g:ctrlp_cache_dir = '$HOME/.vim/cache/ctrlp'
   let g:ctrlp_max_files = 1000
   let g:ctrlp_max_history = &history
   let g:ctrlp_max_depth = 10
   let g:ctrlp_user_command = [
         \ '.git', 'cd %s && git ls-files . -co --exclude-standard',
         \ 'rg %s --files --color=never --glob ""',
         \ 'find %s -type f'
         \ ]
   let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = {
     \ 'dir': '\v[\/](\.git\|dist)$',
     \ 'file': '\v\.(exe|so|dll)$',
   \ }
   "let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = 'dist'
   " let g:ctrlp_user_command = ['rg --files']
   let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 'ra'
   let g:ctrlp_reuse_window = 'startify'
map ff :CtrlP<cr>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Answer 1:**

Please add following line in your `.vimrc`

```
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = 'dist'
```

*I placed this line at last position in `.vimrc`*

---

**Answer 2:**

`\v` search for "*one vertical whitespace character: line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, paragraph or line separator*".

For details visit [rexegg](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html).

Answer (score 1):

Vim's regexes are unfortunately not like any other systems, making them cumbersome and painful to work with. I'm not sure if CtrlP's ignore supports `\v,` I wouldn't add it here. I would also remove the leading slash. Try this (and restarting Vim):

```
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = {
    \ 'dir': '\.git\|dist$'
\ }
```

The `\v` is the "very magic" switch, which you should **always** use for searching in Vim (again, unsure if CtrlP supports it), to make them more usable:

```
nnoremap / /\v
```

It makes special characters like `+` behave like normal regex characters, instead of poorly defined Vim regex characters.

Answer (score 0):

if you use `g:ctrlp_user_command`, `g:ctrlp_custom_ignore` then will not work. rg can ignore files too, just put them into `.gitignore`, rg will ignore any files and directories in `.gitignore`.